# Error while installing ruby-1.8.7 on Fedora 15

Tags: ruby, rvm

Using RVM, I tried to install ree-1.8.7-2011.03 after installing Fedora 15 and I get the following error. Using `rvm install ree-1.8.7-2011.03` on Ubuntu 11.04 works fine..

Same error (and solution) with MRI ruby-1.8.7-p334 on Fedora 15.

Any ideas as to how to fix this?

```
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/ryguy/.rvm/src/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/source/ext/dl'
gcc -I/opt/local/include -I. -I/opt/local/include -I../.. -I../../. -I../.././ext/dl -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DHAVE_DLOPEN -DHAVE_DLCLOSE -DHAVE_DLSYM -DHAVE_DLERROR    -I. -fPIC -g -O2   -fno-defer-pop -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -c ptr.c
gcc -I/opt/local/include -I. -I/opt/local/include -I../.. -I../../. -I../.././ext/dl -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DHAVE_DLOPEN -DHAVE_DLCLOSE -DHAVE_DLSYM -DHAVE_DLERROR    -I. -fPIC -g -O2   -fno-defer-pop -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -c handle.c
Generating callback.func
Generating cbtable.func
gcc -I/opt/local/include -I. -I/opt/local/include -I../.. -I../../. -I../.././ext/dl -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DHAVE_DLOPEN -DHAVE_DLCLOSE -DHAVE_DLSYM -DHAVE_DLERROR    -I. -fPIC -g -O2   -fno-defer-pop -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -c dl.c
In file included from dl.c:104:0:
callback.func:1:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
callback.func:1:7: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘long’
In file included from dl.c:104:0:
callback.func:78:33: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘(’ token
callback.func:79:3: warning: data definition has no type or storage class [enabled by default]
callback.func:79:24: error: ‘proc’ undeclared here (not in a function)
callback.func:79:39: error: ‘argc’ undeclared here (not in a function)
callback.func:79:45: error: ‘argv’ undeclared here (not in a function)
callback.func:82:1: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘}’ token
dl.c:106:1: error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘static’
make[1]: *** [dl.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/ryguy/.rvm/src/ree-1.8.7-2011.03/source/ext/dl'
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: What's the output of `rvm notes`?

Comment: Why is it adding /opt/local/include to the include path? Did you do that?

Comment: @Andy gist.github.com/992640 @noodl All I did was `rvm install ree-1.8.7-2011.03`

Comment: I did install all packages required within `rvm notes` except yum couldn't find iconv-devel

Comment: Small update: in callback.fun, the very last two lines is this: http://gist.github.com/992644 It is clear that somehow this code is getting cut off but I do not understand why.

Comment: go and try install ree by yourself from http://www.rubyenterpriseedition.com/download.html this might give additional input what is going on

Comment: @mpapis RVM just downloads the same exact package from that site. Here's a Gist of the the output of the command and the above is from the install log. https://gist.github.com/549494e3d37c43175a13

Comment: Yup, just tried to manually install REE and I get the same result

Comment: yes the package itself is the same, but rvm applies following patches before compilation `readline-fix.diff` `zlib-gc-fix.diff` `fix-irb-completion.diff`, if there is a problem that could be solved by patch to ree then you can apply that patch when installing using `--patch` rvm command line option

Comment: I get the same error on this when installing ruby-1.8.7-p352. It appears that for some reason, miniruby (which is used to bootstrap these files) isn't properly putting out the right information.

Comment: Okay, so editing the makefile within the directory, the output of the function continues past the end of the file. Some how, the piping isn't working. Which makes ZERO sense. But when not outputting it to the target file, it works. The entire rest of the function is put out.

Comment: @c00lryguy, are you ready to accept an answer, so I can award the bounty?

Comment: @Fabio: I never fixed the problem. My desktop PC's power supply failed and I bought a laptop.

Comment: fixed in rvm 1.9.1 (or just get head)

Answer (score 28):

This also happens when installing ruby-1.8.7 with rvm in Fedora 15.

Reinier Balt's answer also works, in my case I had to install system wide ruby using yum.

Here's what I did:

```
cd ~/.rvm/src/ruby-1.8.7-p334/ext/dl
ruby mkcallback.rb > callback.func
ruby mkcbtable.rb > cbtable.func
```

Comment: I also needed: yum install gdbm.x86_64 gdbm-devel.x86_64, hope it helps someone.

Comment: This worked for me installing rvm as root.  I did not need the gdbm* packages.

Comment: This worked for me, however I also had to yum install ruby-devel

Answer (score 14):

I saw this too

I went into the src/ext/dl directory and manually generated callback.func and cbtable.func which are both incomplete. I had to do

```
rm callback.func
touch callback.func
ruby mkcallback.rb >> callback.func
```

(repeat for cbtable)

Somehow the simple ruby `mkcallback.rb > callback.func` did not work

then rerun `rvm install 1.8.7` which will not overwrite your changes.

Comment: It didn't worked on my setup (Fedora Core 15, rvm installed as root, installing ree). The `ruby` call kept failing with the message: `mkcallback.rb:6:in 'require': no such file to load -- dlconfig (LoadError) from mkcallback.rb:6`

Comment: You may also encounter: mkmf.rb can't find header files for ruby at /usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h in which case you need to install the ruby-devel package

Answer (score 14):

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/5108

[[tl;dr: see patch at bottom]]

Comment: This is the root cause of it, and is the proper solution, unlike my hack :)

Comment: I am on archlinux. I downloaded the patch mentioned in the answer and did `$ rvm install 1.8.7-p352 --patch /path/to/downloaded/patch.patch`. It worked w/o any issues.

Comment: I can confirm that this patch works on Fedora 16. Make sure to run `rvm cleanup all` to remove any stale bad files before attempting to install with the patch.

Comment: @csabahenk Can you post specific details (like what is the patch, or where to download it)? That site is asking me to login, and even though I have a login, after logging in, it says "You are not authorized to access this page.".

Comment: @TylerCollier: I see that unfortunately they took that bug off of their Redmine. Too bad. My old login, with which I filed the bug, is not working either (if I try to reset my password, it complains of an unknown email address; when I try to register with that email again, it complains that login is already taken :) ), and you've already told what's the case with a new account.

Comment: @TylerCollier: As for the patch, unfortunately I don't have it archived, but the discussion around the bug has been kept in Google groups, where you can see a detailed analysis of the issue: https://groups.google.com/d/msg/ruby-core-google/WzEO1uNAXAw/UXFUN-vxqqwJ

Once you understand that, it's easy to fix 1.8.7's mkmf.rb.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why this happens, but it appears that the redirection to the file doesn't completely redirect the output. As a temporary hack/fix, that does get it working, you can pipe it through tee. It gets the job done, but is certainly not the proper solution.

Patch:
https://gist.github.com/1083163

This patch when applied like so: `rvm install --patch /path/to/Fedora-15-ruby-1.8.7-p352.patch%0 ruby-1.8.7` will work. I will test it with ree as well and update.

**EDIT**: This same patch also works with ree.

`rvm install --patch /path/to/Fedora-15-ruby-1.8.76-p352.patch%0 ree` successfully installed a working ree for me.

Comment: This answer looks promising, can anyone check its validity so I can award the bounty? I actually gave up on Fedora 15 and installed Ubuntu, which worked nicely.

Comment: Heh, I don't think it's going to make it in 1 hour, but thanks for the consideration ;)

Comment: The patch didn't work but I modified the ext/dl/depend file as the patch says and it now works fine, thanks

Answer (score 0):

patch from user865548 is now available in RVM (will be `1.9.1` or just `rvm get head`)